# passing float gives garbage value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm dealing with some very weird issues by simply trying to pass a float parameter in obj-c.

I have a method which is called via an NSNotification:

```
    - (void)presetChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {

float newValue = [[S76PresetManager sharedManager] getValueForKey:symbol];

[self setValue:newValue animated:YES];
[PdBase sendFloat:newValue toReceiver:symbol];
}
```

When I run this through the debugger, a float (say 0.5) will remain the same and get sent to the [PdBase sendFloat:] line. However, in the [self setValue:animated:] call, I get a garbage value of 3.68934881e+19. This is very strange. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Nothing special was happening in [self setValue:animated:], just doing some bounds checking before sending it to another method...

```
    - (void)setValue:(float)newValue animated:(BOOL)animated {
float oldValue = value;

if (newValue < 0.0)
    value = 0.0;
else if (newValue > maxValue)
    value = maxValue;
else
    value = newValue;

[self valueDidChangeFrom:oldValue to:value animated:animated];
    }
```

Comment: And what does the setValue call look like?

Comment: can you please show the method definition for the setValue:animated: ?

Comment: what about in the header file? (If it's undeclared in the header, and your setValue:animated: method is later in the source than presetChanged: then you could mangle the argument as the signature will default to an argument type of id -- although the compiler should warn you if that's the case...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you aren't doing anything strange in [self setValue:newValue animated:YES]...

How about:

```
NSNumber *newValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[S76PresetManager sharedManager] getValueForKey:symbol]];

[self setValue:newValue animated:YES];
[PdBase sendFloat:[newValue floatValue] toReceiver:symbol];
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Kind of strange how I wasn't able to pass a simple float parameter though...

Comment: If the type declared for setValue: is (id) or (NSNumber *) then you need to pass an object, instead of a raw float value, and that's why the above code worked for you.